# Rails Odd Even If Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dom

I have a loop for my Activity model

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
<div>
    <div class="cell">
        <%= image_tag(activity.image) %>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <h4><%= activity.title %></h4>
        <p><%= activity.description %></p>
        <span><%= activity.distance %></span>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I want to create a zig-zag effect, so I need to re-arrange the HTML for every even activity, so the markup will look like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h4><%= activity.title %></h4>
    <p><%= activity.description %></p>
    <span><%= activity.distance %></span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <%= image_tag(activity.image) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this with an if statement? Something like this:

```
<% if activity.odd? %>
 <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
   <div>
     <div class="cell">
   <%= image_tag(activity.image) %>
 </div>
 <div class="cell">
   <h4><%= activity.title %></h4>
   <p><%= activity.description %></p>
   <span><%= activity.distance %></span>
 </div>
   </div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <div>
      <div class="cell">
    <h4><%= activity.title %></h4>
    <p><%= activity.description %></p>
    <span><%= activity.distance %></span>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <%= image_tag(activity.image) %>
      </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. The first and best way is to do this with CSS's `nth-child` selector, assuming it's possible to achieve your desired effect purely through CSS. Use `nth-child(odd)` or `nth-child(even)`, as described in [Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css)
2. If you're iterating over a collection using `.each`, you can add a `.with_index` and check whether the index is odd or even:

   ```
   <% @activities.each.with_index do |activity, index| %>
     <% if index.odd? %>
       ...
     <% else %>
       ...
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
   ```

   Note that by default the index is zero-based, so your first element will be considered "even". You can pass a starting index of `1` to `with_index` if you want the alternating to start odd instead:

   ```
   <% @activities.each.with_index(1) do |activity, index| %>
   ```
3. An alternative to using `with_index` is to use Rails' `cycle` helper, which "magically" returns the next argument in rotation each time its invoked:

   ```
   <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
     <% if cycle('odd', 'even') == 'odd' %>
       ...
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
   ```

Also note that this is a fantastic opportunity for refactoring. You should distill the two reused `cell` divs into their own partials and render them in the order you want:

```
<% if index.odd? %>
  <%= render h4_part %>
  <%= render img_part %>
<% else %>
  <% render img_part %>
  <% render h4_part %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: or you could use the same html for odd and even divs, but solve the zig-zag in the css, also using the cycle-trick to set the classes of the divs.

Comment: @niels That would be my preferred solution

Comment: @niels I've tried for an hour to solve the problem with CSS. I was using nth-child, but that's not compatible with IE. I tried flipping the divs using table-header-row, but then I can't float them left.

Comment: If you want to use css then use meagar's `cycle` method to add class="odd" or class="even" to each row, also change the class names from just "cell" to "image-cell" and "info-cell" (or something). Then in your css you can do something like `.odd .image-cell {float: left;} .odd .info-cell {float: right;}` and `.even .image-cell {float: right;} .even .info-cell {float: left;}`