# TR alternate background colour with unequal number of TD

Tags: jquery, css, css-tables

I am trying to have alternate background colour for each .
I understand i can use:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

As [another stack question says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-by-css), however, that only works if we have same number of `<td>`s, but in case we have different number of them, we won't have a full coloured row but it will rather stop to the last td.

Is there way I could do it with only css or any jQuery in regards?

Comment: Doesn't matter how many cells you have, the rule above applies to rows only.

Comment: Do you want to alternate the colors of the rows or the cells? In the first case, you don't need to worry.

Comment: 'different number of them'? What do you mean? Different amount of `td` per row? You know that is invalid right (without rowspan)?

Comment: @putvande you are correct

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a class to each row. It should be pretty simple if you are generating your table dynamically.

```
<style>
    .rowOdd { background: #C0C0C0; }
    .rowEven { background: #CACACA; }
</style>

<table>
    <tr class="rowOdd">
    (...)
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEven">      
    (...)
    </tr>
 </table>
```

etc... Or if your layout is really complicated (lots of merged cells) then you can add similar class to each td individually instead of tr.

Comment: yeah that's quite obvious but if I have less td in a row, that won't work. I guess it's just invalid not to display a all the td unless we use rowspan, which in that case the row will be fine as it be equal width with all the other

Comment: Och, that's what you mean. Yes, as far as I know it's bad practice not to have an equal number of td's unless you use rowspans. In most cases table sizing gets screwed up if some rows are different! Afteral, it's a table, just like in excel, and not a free do-what-you-want layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go the CSS3 approach.

This site is really good at explaining all the different nth child syntax that is available

http://nthmaster.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use odd/even numbers to manipulate each row seperately. I think you need a real demo here to understand better.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Frgq/)

```
tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background: red;
}         
tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr:nth-child(2n+1)` for odd numbers or `tr:nth-child(2n+1)` in plain css.

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td
{
background-color:#F5F5F5
}
```