# Why does my alternate row background color not work for my table?

Tags: css

I am using the following CSS and HTML:

```
table.grid tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #888;
}


<table class="form grid">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>xx</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>xx</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>xx</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>xx</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The table shows up fine but there is no different background color shading for the rows. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you manipulate the table from `.form` class? What browser are you using? Do you have `td` background styling in `.grid`?

Comment: I am using the Chrome browser. I was under the impression that it would work on all of the later browsers now.

Comment: You must have some overriding styles. Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/UHM9m/

Comment: It works in the latest Firefox browser

Comment: @Melina Please verify that you do not set td background in `.grid` applied tables.

Comment: I found out there's a background on the <td>. Thanks for the advice / fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting your CSS selector to `table.grid tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {`.

This may help in case you have other CSS in your document affecting the `background` property of `td` elements, while also allowing you to do column-specific styling (e.g. for sorting). I find this preferable to applying the `background` property to `tr` elements.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ctdu/) demonstrating that this should indeed work with your CSS unless something else in your CSS is affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered several times before. There are known compatibility issues with CSS3 and IE which are known to break the nth-child selector. You may have to use JQuery to do it instead. Here is some info which may help

[Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css)