# Alternate table row color even if row is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablerow

I want different colors for alternate table rows even when i delete a row in middle.

HTML

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>Row 1</td><td><a class="sam" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2</td><td><a class="sams" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3</td><td><a class="sam" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 4</td><td><a class="sams" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 5</td><td><a class="sam" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    update_rows();
    $("a").click(function(){$(this).parent().parent().remove();update_rows();});
});
function update_rows()
{
    $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#aaa");
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#eee");
}
```

css

```
.sam
{
background-color:#FF00FF;
}
.sams
{
background-color:#0000FF;
}
```

the above code change the row color but not the cell which has link.
Please help me to solve the problem

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmBwZ/3/)**

Comment: Use CSS and browser handles it.

Comment: @krishna: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css The downside is that IE8 doesn't support it.

Comment: @stackoverflow, the solution required here is different from solutions provided in the question you specified,because i want this to be working in IE and i need to change the class of cell having hyperlink, which is not answered there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the class as well

```
function update_rows() {
    $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#aaa").find('a').removeClass('sam').addClass('sams');
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#eee").find('a').removeClass('sams').addClass('sam');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZTdn5/)

---

Use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) if want to support only [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child#Browser_compatibility) - Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p3PMg/)

```
tr:nth-child(odd) a {
    background-color:#FF00FF;
}
tr:nth-child(even) a {
    background-color:#0000FF;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#aaa;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

then

```
$(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

---

Also note: use `$(this).closest('tr').remove()` instead of `$(this).parent().parent().remove()`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
  <style>
     tr:nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color:#e3e3e3;
     }

     td:nth-of-type(odd) {
        color:#d04242;
     }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS3 for the styling:

```
<table id="whatever">
  <tr><td>Row 1</td><td><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2</td><td><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3</td><td><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 4</td><td><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 5</td><td><a href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>
</table>
<style>
#whatever tr {
    background-color: #AAA;
}
#whatever tr a {
    background-color:#F0F;
}
#whatever tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
#whatever tr:nth-child(odd) a {
    background-color:#00F;
}
</style>
<script>
$("#whatever a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
</script>
```

Now no manual updating, neither for the link classes nor the row backgrounds is needed. See [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmBwZ/8/).

Answer (score 0):

works perfectly with your tr. the link color doesent change because youre not targeting it with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle 
You need the update the class sam and sams

```
      $("tr:even td a").removeClass("sam").removeClass("sams").addClass("sam");
      $("tr:odd td a").removeClass("sam").removeClass("sams").addClass("sams");
```

[Check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmBwZ/5/)