# Make table display alternating color background when sorted

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have data outputed into a table that can be found by going to http://pa.sitescribers.com/perfect-fit-search/ and clicking "Click the Magic Button"

The problem is when you click on any of the headers to sort the table, it doesn't keep an alternating color background scheme.  Its probably a quick fix but I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The link shows a js bug in console. When you fix it, follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at your table in your link, nothing happens when I click the headers, and you have no colors on the rows. But I can make a guess as to why you would have trouble if those features were active.

Instead of setting individual classes on each table row (like 'odd' and 'even'), try using CSS child selectors to define the styles for the rows dynamically like this:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

You can read more about that [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) and see an example.

Comment: Sorry its the way it was coded.  I am editing this for a friend.  If you go to http://pa.sitescribers.com/perfect-fit-search/ and click "Click the Magic Button"  it will take you to the correct table.

Comment: I tested my solution on the link you posted and it works. You just have to remove the styles for the table cells, such as  `tr.odd td {background: #003040;}`, `tr.even td {background: transparent;}` and `td {background: #FFFF99;}`