# Alternate table row color using CSS, individual cells get colored not the even rows

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, background-color, css-tables

Somehow I can't figure out the following: [Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css)

If I use the code suggested in the aforementioned topic the even cells get colored (the first, third and fifth. There is a total of 5 cells in a row). It doesn't matter if I use 'even' or 'odd'.

```
td:nth-child(odd)
{
    background: #f5f6fa;
}
```

If use the following code, all the rows get colored.:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)
  {
        background: #f5f6fa;
  }
```

Comment: provide html and full css

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@svdh You've got tags outside of your body and html tags also which in a normal web page wouldn't be rendered. The problem with your HTML is you're setting up loads of tables instead of one with multiple rows. It should be like this.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>One</td>
  <td>One.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Two</td>
  <td>Two.</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Three</td>
  <td>Three.</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle here.. 
https://jsfiddle.net/fo7Ldfqs/

UPDATED:

If you've got multiple tables and you're trying to color every other one then just use:

```
table:nth-child(odd){background:#ff0000;}
```

Fiddle here.. https://jsfiddle.net/4641ph6u/

Comment: thanks that makes sense. Thanks!. Unfortunately the Plugin I use, creates 'loads of tables' (Download Manager). I provide the mark-up (HTML) for 1 'package' and when I create one page with several 'packages' the plugin creates several tables, resulting in loads of tables.

Comment: You mean if use the correct markup?  (the one you suggested) I use the following : <div class='w3eden'><div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td>[icon]</td>
    <td>[title]</td> 
    <td>[file_size]</td>   
    <td>[download_url] title=" height="15"  width="14">
</a> [update_date]</td> 
    <td><a href="[page_url]">View details</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

Comment: hmm.. i'll try to clarify it:  I have 10 tables, all with the same class. I would like to add alternating coloring to the tables. Table1: red Table2: white: Table3: red. and so forth.. Thanks for the tip.  I use Notepad++

Comment: @svdh I've updated my answer and included a fiddle. Hope it helps.

Comment: @svdh No problems at all. Happy to help =) Could you kindly mark this as the answer so the thread becomes closed.