# Creating Outlook HTML table from PSCustomObject

Tags: html, email, powershell, outlook

I've got a PSCustomObject `$result` which contains data that I filter through with the purpose of creating an HTML table that will be sent via `Send-MailMessage`.

I can create an HTML table that looks great but I'm trying to insert this table into the body of an Outlook email, which does not seem to work with the CSS because in Outlook Word does the rendering (from what I read).  If simply attaching the htm file to the email is my only option, I'll go that route but my preference is inserting the table into the email body.

```bsh
$denied = @()
foreach ($a in $result) {
  if ($a.MaintenanceWindow -eq 'Not found!' -or $a.LastReboot -eq 'Access Denied!') {
    $denied += $a
 }

} #end foreach

$a = @'
"<style>"
"BODY{background-color:lightgrey;}"
"TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
"TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
"TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
"</style>"
'@

$denied | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a | Out-File D:\c.htm;
ii D:\c.htm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the table as the body of the email that is easily done.

```
# -Body expects one string. Out-String will take care of that. 
$HTMLBody = $denied | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a | Out-String
# To be sure it is rendered as HTML we use the switch -BodyAsHTML
Send-MailMessage -To $toAddresses -From $fromAddresses -Subject "All over this table" -Body $HTMLBody  -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer server
```

Now the table will be the mail.

---

## Couple of things I wanted to point out outside of that

I had an issue with your `$a`. I removed all of the outer double quotes. Was not reading with them present.

```
$a = @'
<style>
BODY{background-color:lightgrey;}
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
'@
```

While we are talking about `$a` you use that as your foreach process variable and you CSS variable. Use meaningful names and you wont get stuck with mistakes where you are overwriting your own variables by accident.

You are making the `$denied` array from the filtered contents of an existing array. While there are not too many items that is a performance hog and not required.

```
$denied = $result | Where-Object{
  $_.MaintenanceWindow -eq 'Not found!' -or
  $_.LastReboot -eq 'Access Denied!'
}
```

Comment: Looking great, I admit I was rushing and mixed two scripts.  Ended up taking this a step further with alternate row shading using [this great script](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1745-set-alternatingrows-function-modify-your-html-table-to-have-alternating-row-colors) and everything looks great, thank you!

Comment: @user4317867 You could also just use simple css if you client/browser will support them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css. `tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #000000}` for example

Comment: Outlook doesn't seem to accept certain CSS elements.  At least that was the results of my search.  [More info here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: @user4317867 Guess that wont work then. I used that before but not in mail.

Comment: Correct, its no big deal to just include the Function `Set-AlternatingRows` within my main function.  Works great!