# After removing row from table add class and show the message,also keep zebra style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to find a way to show the message in the row where I removed record. I have a button on one of my td tags. After I click on that button I have function with ajax call that removes record from DB but at the same time I would like to show the message inside of that row for 2sec and then fade out that message. Also, I want to keep my zebra style in my table. Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr class="~[evenoddrow]">
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>
      <input id="delDel_(id)" type="checkbox" />
      <a name="delRec" onClick="recDelete('myForm',id)"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript/JQuery code:

```
function recDelete(frm,recId){
    $('#delRec_'+recId).prop('checked', true );
    var myForm = $j('#'+frm).serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'test.html',
        data:myForm
    })
    .done(function(data){
        if( $.trim(data) == 'success'){
            $('#delRec_' + recId).closest('tr').addClass("feedback").show().html("Record deleted.").delay(1500).fadeOut('slow');
        }else{
            $('#delRec_' + recId).closest('tr').addClass("feedback2").show().html("Error deleting");        
            }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
        myFunc(errorThrown)
    });     
}
```

My current code is showing message created with feedback class that I added but that row jumps up and down after my message is displayed and fade out. I checked my css and tried to adjust height and width but that did not help. I think that something is odd in my JQuery where I'm adding class to another element. Also my zebra style is off after I show that message. I wan to keep that style after message fades out. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Are you manually adding odd/even classes for Zebra? Have you tried to just use odd/even selectors and not worry about classes?

Comment: I have class="~[evenoddrow]" on each table row that crates alternate colors. No I have not tried to use odd/even. Not even sure how that works. Can you provide any example?

Comment: tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
}

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css

Comment: set the table css even and odd from css