# change background of every second row in gridview if row is visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` and on `RowDataBound` I use this code to change the background of every second row so the `gridview` can be read better:

```
 if (e.Row.RowIndex % 2 != 0)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f2f2f2");
            }
```

After that I use a `dropdown` to show only relevant rows of my `gridview` and hide `(visible = false)` the rows I didn't want to display. The rownumber doesn't change so the different background doesn't match for every second row now.

Now I'm looking to get the rownumbers of only the visible rows to change the color of every second row. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS technique mentioned in [Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css):

```
.alternatingRows > tbody > tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

The style class is applied to the GridView itself:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="alternatingRows" ... >
```

Answer (score 4):

Try AlternatingRowStyle property of the gridView.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.alternatingrowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

A documentation on msdn to get you started.

Comment: thanks but the result is still the same, I only hide the row (`visible=false`) and not delete them

Comment: Well then, try to change the AlternatingRowStyle property from your codeback file. Where you assign the row's visiblity to false just after that set the alternatingrowstyle property of the gridview to whatever you want to. Now I have worked in C# so in C# you can do it like this

`dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;`

Comment: More information here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.alternatingrowsdefaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the answer of ConnorsFan works for me. +1 anyway. Thanks