# How to add alternate row color to a CSS class

Tags: css

How would I add alternate row color to this class:

```
.widget li { 
       border: none; padding: 14px 0 0px; 
}
```

I see instructions like these:

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

[Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css)

https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/the-css3-anthology-4th-edition/preview/how-do-i-display-table-rows-in-alternating-colors-4bcb9a2

But this seems more complicate than that. Can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
.widget li:nth-child(even){
       background: #CCC
 }

.widget li:nth-child(odd){
       background: #000
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you want alternate text-colors on `li` elements or divs with class `widget`. If you mean the latter then try the following:

```
.widget {
  color: myoddcolr;
}

.widget:nth-of-type(odd) {
  color: myoddcolr;
}
```

Comment: I think it's quite clear he wants to target `li`, as that's what his CSS is showing

Comment: As a non native English speaker I couldn't decipher what (s)he meant. `.widget li` isn't a class. And usually `li` elements are not taken as rows -- cf. the row col grid system

Comment: I get that, but seeing as he's talking about widgets, it's fair to assume each `li` will be a widget block, which could be a row in a column... Plus he wants alternating 'rows', which would make sense if you have a bunch of `li` items.

Comment: @Lee Yes you are right. OP is using `widget` on `ul`. `widget` is column and the the `li`s are rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :nth-child(2n+1). I hope this will help you!

```css
.widget {
  padding-left: 0px;
 }
 .widget li{
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 .widget li:nth-child(2n+1){
  background: #ccc;
 }
 .widget li:nth-child(2n+2){
  background: #eee;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="widget">
 <li>Row - 1</li>
 <li>Row - 2</li>
 <li>Row - 3</li>
 <li>Row - 4</li>
 <li>Row - 5</li>
 <li>Row - 6</li>
</ul>
```