# Set alternate color for tables rows and columns in css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have also tried using below codes. it doesn't work for this case.

[image: String Text]

```
table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}
table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your markup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate table row color using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css)

Comment: Post your code with [code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) It will be more helpful to get issue with your code.

Answer (score 6):

### Alternating rows

See the difference: we are using `odd` and `even` on `tr`, not `td`:

```css
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) >td{
    background-color: #eee;
}
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr>
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr>
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr>
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It seems this first part was answered here:
[Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/)

### Alternating rows and columns:

If you want the "doubled" alternate, extend the concept to all combinations:

```css
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)> td:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#aaa}
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)> td:nth-child(even){background-color:#888}
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#eee}
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(even){background-color:#ddd}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr>
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr>
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr>
    <tr><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td><td>. . . . .</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column `css` has overridden the row `css`. Hence changed them for `odd` and `even` rows separately as below.

```css
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #F7F7F7 !important;
}

table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}

table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #F2F2F2 !important;
}
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 3 Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 3 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 4 Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 4 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```