# Alternate row color in HTML table with rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm a little stuck on this one. I need the rows containing "Row Title" who has a determined "rowspan" alternate in color. The color must cover the entire width of the table and the entire height of that row. For example, one row should be in blue and another in red and so on. I've tried with css advanced selectors like `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` but it doesn't work for me. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Here I show my code.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}

tbody * {
  font-weight: normal;
}

tr, th {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

th {
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.add-color {
  position: relative;
}

.add-color:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="add-color" rowspan="2">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A table can have [multiple `tbody` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#Multiple_bodies). You can use `tbody` with `nth-child` to have different colors for your groups of rows:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}

tbody * {
  font-weight: normal;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

tr,
th {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

th {
  width: 33.33333%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="add-color" rowspan="2">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following code using background color class without your stucture change.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: #000;
}

thead {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}

tbody * {
  font-weight: normal;
}

tr, th {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

th {
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.add-color {
  position: relative;
}

.add-color:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #111;
}
tr.bg-gray {
 background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

      <tr class="bg-gray">
      <th rowspan="3" class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-gray">
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-gray">
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="add-color" rowspan="2">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-gray">
      <th class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" class="add-color">Row Title</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
      <th>Bla Bla</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```