# How can I select all the elements whose attribute value is odd

Tags: css, css-selectors, attributes

How can I select all the elements whose attribute value is odd.
eg:

```
<tr class="MuiTableRow-root" index="0" level="0" path="0" style="transition: all 300ms ease 0s; pointer-events: inherit;">
<tr class="MuiTableRow-root" index="1" level="0" path="0" style="transition: all 300ms ease 0s; pointer-events: inherit;">
<tr class="MuiTableRow-root" index="2" level="0" path="0" style="transition: all 300ms ease 0s; pointer-events: inherit;">
```

I want to apply styles on tr whose index attribute value is odd using css.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```css
[index$='1'],
[index$='3'],
[index$='5'],
[index$='7'],
[index$='9'] {
  color: red;
}

.MuiTableRow-root {
  font-size:25px;
}
.MuiTableRow-root::before {
  content:attr(index);
}
```

```html
<div class="MuiTableRow-root" index="0" level="0" path="0"></div>
<div class="MuiTableRow-root" index="1" level="0" path="0"></div>
<div class="MuiTableRow-root" index="2" level="0" path="0"></div>
<div class="MuiTableRow-root" index="19" level="0" path="0"></div>
<div class="MuiTableRow-root" index="33" level="0" path="0"></div>
<div class="MuiTableRow-root" index="42" level="0" path="0"></div>
<div class="MuiTableRow-root" index="40" level="0" path="0"></div>
```

Comment: @krissh here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors also don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Dropping in with a little extra context and a Tailwind solution.

I'm not sure if this was the OP's use case, but I stumbled upon this question because I was making a table with virtualized rows, meaning the typical `:odd` and `:even` selectors wouldn't cut it to apply zebra striping (alternating row colors). The dynamic nature of virtualized rows means the odd- and evenness of a given row changes as earlier rows are added and removed from the table as you scroll.

Similar to OP's example, however, I was able to apply a stable index to each row using a data attribute. So styling based on the evenness of that attribute would work consistently.

Temani's answer is clever because it utilizes the ["ends with" attribute selector (i.e. [attr$=value])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_5) to pick out all the values that an odd number can possibly end with: 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9. You can similarly target even numbers since they will always end with 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8.

My project happens to use Tailwind, so I wanted to turn this into a [Tailwind custom variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) with support for the `group-*` and `peer-*` state modifiers (since that's so often needed in nested table markup). Here is what I ended up with in case it helps others:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // Add a variant for applying styles based whether an element's
    // `data-index` attribute is odd or even.
    const endings = { even: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], odd: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] };
    const options = { values: { odd: 'odd', even: 'even' } };

    matchVariant(
      'data-index',
      (v) => endings[v].map((n) => `&[data-index$="${n}"]`),
      options
    );

    matchVariant(
      'group-data-index',
      (v) => endings[v].map((n) => `:merge(.group)[data-index$="${n}"] &`),
      options
    );

    matchVariant(
      'peer-data-index',
      (v) => endings[v].map((n) => `:merge(.peer)[data-index$="${n}"] ~ &`),
      options
    );
  ]
}
```

With that in place, alternating rows between different shades of gray looks something like this:

```html
<tr class="data-index-even:bg-gray-200 data-index-odd:bg-gray-100" data-index="0">
<tr class="data-index-even:bg-gray-200 data-index-odd:bg-gray-100" data-index="1">
<tr class="data-index-even:bg-gray-200 data-index-odd:bg-gray-100" data-index="2">
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `:nth-child(odd)` on the end of your selector.

Example:

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: the data elements can't be guaranteed to be alternating, therefor this wouldn't actually solve the issue.