# Array.map / Filter a contigous array and then re-order it to be contiguous again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, array.prototype.map

Using React, I have a list component that uses array.map to render a list of items.

The list items are variegated; every other list item has a different background color which depends on if the id field of the data structure that feeds the list item is even or odd:

```
  ...

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  even: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  odd: {
    backgroundColor: "#c8c9c7",
  },
}));

...

const classes = useStyles();

...

{!list || list.length < 1 ? (
    <p>You have no assets selected...</p>
  ) : (
    list.map((items) => (
      <ListItem
        className={items.id % 2 === 0 ? classes.even : classes.odd}
        key={items.id}
      >
    ...
      />
    </ListItem>
  ))
)}
```

Here is an example of the data structure it uses:

```
{
    {
        "id":0,
        "foo":"This is a bar"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "foo":"This is also a bar"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "foo":"Yes, this too, is a bar"
    }
}
```

I need to remove items. Normal javascript.filter produces non contiguous ids as expected:

```
{
    {
        "id":0,
        "foo":"This is a bar"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "foo":"Yes, this too, is a bar"
    }
}
```

I need them to be contiguous:

```
{
    {
        "id":0,
        "foo":"This is a bar"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "foo":"Yes, this too, is a bar"
    }
}
```

I have a function that does what I need that needs some tweaking:

```
  const handleRemoveAsset = (id) => {
    const arrayCopy = [...assetListItems];
     const filteredArray = arrayCopy
       .filter((item) => item.id !== id)

     for (var i=0; i < filteredArray.length; i++) {
       filteredArray[i].id = i;
     }

    setAssetListItems(filteredArray);
  };
```

This works, but one does not simply for loop using React... I am hoping to use filter and/or map for the entirety of this and not use the for loop that I have.

I read that you can chain filter and map and tried it but couldn't quite work it out. I came up with this:

```
   const filteredArray = array
      .filter((item) => item.id !== id)
      .map((item, index) => {
           item && item.id ? item.id : index)});
```

... which fails to compile with - *expected an assignment to a function call and instead saw an expression* on the line after .map.

Any advice at this point would appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It seems to me that instead the coloring code should be updated to use indices instead of ids.

Comment: You can also use CSS for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css

Comment: Thank you for the responses! My CSS is garbage, but it seems like it would be a lot simpler to use this approach than to build dynamic CSS styling through react. I will explore it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could chain `map` and `filter` and return the new object from `map` which updates the pre-existing id.

```
[...assetListItems]
    .filter(item => item.id !== id)
    .map((item, index) => ({
      ...item,
      id: index,
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you for this example, this works and I will study it to understand map and filter better... You rock, thanks for the fast help!

Answer (score 1):

I just considered another scenario where if the `id` is not starting with `0`. And if you want the starting `id` in the `resultant array` to be as the `id` of the first object then this is just another way of achieving the expected output.

```js
let data = [{id:0, foo:'This is a bar'},{id:1, foo:'This is also a bar'},{id:2, foo:'Yes, this too, is a bar'}];


const filterItems = (items, id) => {
  let lastPushedId = items[0]?.id;
  return items.filter(item => item.id !== id).map(item => ({
    ...item,
    id: lastPushedId++
  }))
}
console.log(filterItems(data, 1));

//`id` of the first object is `3`
data = [{id:3, foo:'This is a bar'},{id:4, foo:'This is also a bar'},{id:5, foo:'Yes, this too, is a bar'}];
console.log(filterItems(data, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```