# Alternate colour columns in dynamically generated divs table

Tags: html, css

I am looking to alternate div table columns (not row) example column 1 red... column 2 blue etc..

```css
.divTable{
        display: table;
        width: 100.0%;
    }
    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
    }
    
    .divTableCell{
        background-color: #F7F8F8;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        display: table-cell;
        padding-top: 25px !important;
        padding-bottom: 18px !important;
    }
    
    .divTableHead{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 1px 1px;
    }
    .divTable h3{color: #376d1b;}
    .divTableHeading, .divTableBody, .divTableFoot, .divTableRow{
       clear: both;
    }
    .divTableHeading{
        background-color: #000;
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    
        border-radius: 0;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0;
        -o-border-radius: 0;
        border: 0;
        
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableHead">#</div>
    <div class="divTableHead">col_red</div>
    <div class="divTableHead">col_blue</div>
    <div class="divTableHead blue">col_green</div>
    <div class="divTableHead green">col_yellow</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class='divTableRow'>
    <div class='divTableCell'>1(4)</div>
    <div class='divTableCell'>record</div>
    <div class='divTableCell'>fail</div>
    <div class='divTableCell'>return</div>
    <div class='divTableCell'>fail</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternate table row color using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084261/alternate-table-row-color-using-css)

Comment: If the linked question does not help: what's your problem? You haven't posted any specific question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.divTableRow :nth-child(2) {background: red}` to make the 2'nd column red, you can do this for all your columns.

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100.0%;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableCell {
  background-color: #F7F8F8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 25px !important;
  padding-bottom: 18px !important;
}

.divTableHead {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1px 1px;
}

.divTable h3 {
  color: #376d1b;
}

.divTableHeading,
.divTableBody,
.divTableFoot,
.divTableRow {
  clear: both;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #000;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTableRow :nth-child(2) {background: red}
.divTableRow :nth-child(3) {background: blue}
.divTableRow :nth-child(4) {background: green}
.divTableRow :nth-child(5) {background: yellow}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableHead">#</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">col_red</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">col_blue</div>
      <div class="divTableHead blue">col_green</div>
      <div class="divTableHead green">col_yellow</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class='divTableRow'>
      <div class='divTableCell'>1(4)</div>
      <div class='divTableCell'>record</div>
      <div class='divTableCell'>fail</div>
      <div class='divTableCell'>return</div>
      <div class='divTableCell'>fail</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth` child
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

```css
.divTableHead:nth-child(2n+3) {
    background: hotpink;
}
```

> The same works for table columns, too, but then there has to be an element in the document that corresponds to the column. HTML provides COL for that. The table has to start with one COL for every column:

```css
.divTableHead:nth-child(2n+3) {
background: hotpink;
}


 .divTable {
 display: table;
 width: 100.0%;
 }
 
 .divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
 }
 
 .divTableCell {
 background-color: #F7F8F8;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 display: table-cell;
 padding-top: 25px !important;
 padding-bottom: 18px !important;
 }
 
 .divTableHead {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 1px 1px;
 }
 
 .divTable h3 {
 color: #376d1b;
 }
 
 .divTableHeading,
 .divTableBody,
 .divTableFoot,
 .divTableRow {
 clear: both;
 }
 
 .divTableHeading {
 background-color: #000;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
 -o-border-radius: 0;
 border: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 
 .divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
 }
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
<div class="divTableRow">
  <div class="divTableHead">#</div>
  <div class="divTableHead">col_red</div>
  <div class="divTableHead">col_blue</div>
  <div class="divTableHead blue">col_green</div>
  <div class="divTableHead green">col_yellow</div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
<div class='divTableRow'>
  <div class='divTableCell'>1(4)</div>
  <div class='divTableCell'>record</div>
  <div class='divTableCell'>fail</div>
  <div class='divTableCell'>return</div>
  <div class='divTableCell'>fail</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nth-child()`:

```css
.divTable{
        display: table;
        width: 100.0%;
    }
    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
    }
    
    .divTableCell{
        background-color: #F7F8F8;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        display: table-cell;
        padding-top: 25px !important;
        padding-bottom: 18px !important;
    }
    
    .divTableHead{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 1px 1px;
    }
    .divTable h3{color: #376d1b;}
    .divTableHeading, .divTableBody, .divTableFoot, .divTableRow{
       clear: both;
    }
    .divTableHeading{
        background-color: #000;
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    
        border-radius: 0;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0;
        -o-border-radius: 0;
        border: 0;
        
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .divTableFoot {
        background-color: #EEE;
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
    .divTableCell:nth-child(5n){
    background: yellow;
    }
    
    .divTableCell:nth-child(5n+1){
      background: red;
    }
    
    .divTableCell:nth-child(5n+2){
        background: blue;

    }
    .divTableCell:nth-child(5n+3){
        background: orange;

    }
    .divTableCell:nth-child(5n+4){
        background: green;

    }
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableHead">#</div>
    <div class="divTableHead">col_red</div>
    <div class="divTableHead">col_blue</div>
    <div class="divTableHead blue">col_green</div>
    <div class="divTableHead green">col_yellow</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class='divTableRow'>
    <div class='divTableCell'>1(4)</div>
    <div class='divTableCell'>record</div>
    <div class='divTableCell'>fail</div>
    <div class='divTableCell'>return</div>
    <div class='divTableCell'>fail</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.divTableCell:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
```

This will alternate color the odd columns. You can set both `even` and `odd` for different colors in columns.