# How to render items using alternating colors based on the items.id in nextjs

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

When rendering a list of data, I need to return it with 2 different colors, for example: the first item background color should be white, and the second items should be gray.
This is what I tried

```
`        
<div className={`cursor-pointer w-full my-1 ${event.id % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-gray50'}` } >
`
```

It only works if the item id is odd, otherwise it does not work.
I would appreciate any suggestions you may have

Comment: simply use `odd:bg-gray-50 even:bg-white` which is inbuilt in tailwindcss :)

Comment: it gives the same color, all gray

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/3084304/535480

Comment: <div className="cursor-pointer w-full my-1  odd:bg-gray-400 even:bg-white" >

Comment: @Divad You can check the demo in tailwindplay https://play.tailwindcss.com/xEWMlzDL1v